# How to excract data from a xsi:type row?

Tags: xsitype

From this XML :

```xml
<Event xsi:type="steps" RealTime="2020-10-08T19:07:51.231079" UpdatedTime="2020-10-08T19:09:54.711" Rev="1" ID="9" Time="297">
   <LOTS OF DATA>
<Event xsi:type="trips" RealTime="2020-10-08T19:07:51.231079" UpdatedTime="2020-10-08T19:09:54.711" Rev="1" ID="9" Time="297">
   <LOTS OF DATA>
<Event xsi:type="steps" RealTime="2020-10-08T19:07:51.231079" UpdatedTime="2020-10-08T19:09:54.711" Rev="1" ID="9" Time="297">
   <LOTS OF DATA>
```

I want to use  `<xsl:for-each select="Steps"` to only read the data in that specific rows.

Its works if have `<Event type="steps">` But not with `<Event xsi:type="steps">`